# How to control remotely the video played on a VR headset?

Tags: android, bluetooth, virtual-reality, google-vr, gear-vr

I'd like to develop an android app that will control the video played on a VR headset.

The app should run on a tablet, i.e external to the headset, and should be able to start and pause the video played on the VR headset.

What is the best solution for doing that ?

Is there any VR headset that would enable playing videos coming from an external source such as a USB connected tablet ?

Answer (score 0):

What about the lg vr?
http://www.lg.com/us/lg-friends/lg-LGR100.AVRZTS-360-vr

Also you can use a simple bluetooth controller to send the commands on the phone

Answer (score 0):

VR Cinema for cardboard let's u play videos in vr 
More info 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.mobius.vrcinema&hl=en

Comment: Thanks but the cardboard requires embedding a phone. The solution I am looking for is to be able to play a video from a tablet outside the headset.